# Square matrix $m \times n$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

The question that I have is the following:

> Prove that if $M$ is an $m \times n$ matrix such that for all B in $F^m$, there is a unique $T \in F^n$ such that $MT = B$ (so $MX=B$ has a unique solution), then $m = n$ and so $M$ is square.

This is for a proof based course on linear algebra. I am aware of the concepts involved but struggle to formulate proofs for abstract matrices and would be grateful for any assistance with this problem.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I couldn't figure out what it means to have an unique T in F^n.

Comment: That's explained in the parenthetical remark: it's another way of saying that the equation $MX=B$ has exactly one solution no matter what $B$ is (not necessarily the same solution, of course).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** What must be the dimension of the column space of $M$, or altenatively, how many linearly independent columns must $M$ have?

Comment: The dimension of the column space of M must be mx1.

Comment: @Shot dimension is not a tuple (*dimensions* would be), but a number of linearly independent directions in a subspace

Comment: oh my bad i mixed em up sry

Comment: Tnx for the hint. It was rlly usefull.

Comment: I solved the question :D